# Invoke method on real object with gmock c++

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I have mocked a function from an object with gmock. Now I want that, every time this function is called, it calls the function of object A passing Param as parameter. 
Following you can find a snippet of the code

```
//class I want to call
class A {
public: 
    void func1(const Param& p) {cout<<p.name_<<endl;};
}

class Param {
public:
    string name_;
}


class IMock {
public:
    virtual void func2(int x) = 0;
}

class Mock : public IMock{
public: 
    MOCK_METHOD(void, func2, (int x), (override));
}
```

Test:

```
A a;
Param param;
Mock mock;
EXPECT_CALL(mock, func2(_))
    .WillOnce(
        testing::WithArg<param>(testing::Invoke(&a, a.func1)));
```

But I have the following compile errors:

- The value of param is not usable in a constant expression
- Invalid use of non static member function virtual void A::func1(const Param&)

Any ideas?

**EDIT 1**

Following @pptaszni response, the new Test code is:

```
TEST(Test_case, test_flow) {
    A a;
    Param param;
    Mock mock;
    ON_CALL(mock, func2(_)).WillDefault(testing::Invoke(
        [&a, &param]() { a.func1(param); })));
    mock.func2(23);
}
```

But now the compiler says:

> no matching function for call to testing::internal::OnCallSpec::WillByDefault(std::decay >::type)
>            [&a, & param]() { a.func1(param); }));
> note: candidate: testing::internal::OnCallSpec& testing::internal::OnCallSpec::WillByDefault(const testing::Action&) [with F = void(int)]
> OnCallSpec& WillByDefault(const Action& action) {
>                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
> note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘std::decay >::type {aka Test_case_test_flow::TestBody()::}’ to ‘const testing::Action&’

I'm using the latest version of googletet avaialble on GitHub (1.10)

Comment: Take a closer look at my answer: "lambda expression must much the signature of your `Mock::func2`". In your case `int` argument is missing. Correct: `[&a, &param](int)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always use lambda expression inside `Invoke`, because IMHO it is the most flexible approach.

```
TEST(xxx, yyy)
{
  A a;
  Param param;
  Mock mock;
  EXPECT_CALL(mock, func2())
    .WillOnce(Invoke([&a, &param]()
    {
      a.func1(param);
    }));
  mock.func2();
}
```

If you don't want to pass references to `a` and `param`, you can create a test fixture, declare them as protected fixture fields and pass `this` to lambda capture block.

Note that the lambda expression must much the signature of your `Mock::func2`. In this example it accepts 0 arguments.

Also, you wrote

> every time this function is called

In this case it is better to use

```
ON_CALL(mock, mocked_method(/*params*/)).WillByDefault(Invoke(/*rest of the code*/));
```

especially if you have the test fixture and you can configure this default action in your fixture's constructor (or `SetUp`).

Comment: I still have this error error: no matching function for call to ‘testing::internal::OnCallSpec<void(const Param&, const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&, const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&)>::WillByDefault(std::decay<testname::TestBody()::<lambda()> >::type)’
           [&a, &param]() { a.func1(param); }));

Comment: Which means you just have some typo elsewhere in your code (probably mock definition). Post [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), because the code included in your question does not compile also for other reasons. Specify gtest version you use.

Comment: I'm using the latest version of googlemocks from github, I think is 1.10